# Is there any domain of mathematics that deals with abstraction of measure theory?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, soft-question

In the recent past, I got the opportunity to study measure theory and I am overwhelmed. The reason is that I realized the probability theory I studied over several years is just an instantiation of measure theory with few caveats.

To my surprise, no introductory book on probability I studied directly mention this. So, I don't want to miss the opportunity of studying the abstraction of measure theory, if any.

So, my question is obvious: Is there any branch of mathematics that deals with the abstraction of measure theory?

Comment: A bit of notation: Is "abstract measure theory" the "abstraction of measure theory"?

Comment: @RichardChen If I understand correctly, I don't think so. To be concise I need (probability theory, measure theory), (measure theory, ??????). The operation is abstraction.

Comment: That would probably set theory.

Comment: Well measure theory is a part of real analysis, although i wouldn't say that it is an abstraction of it

Comment: Over 20 years ago, Noel Vaillant attempted to put some probability tutorials up at http://probability.net/  though this turned out to be much more about measure theory than probability itself, and largely lost the probability motivation and turned out to be an application of analysis (both real and complex)

Comment: Two possible generalizations: [finitely additive "measures"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22finitely+additive%22+%22content%22&filter=0) (studied in depth in [**Theory of Charges: A Study of Finitely Additive Measures**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0124109845) by Rao/Rao, for instance) and [additive set functions](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22additive+set+functions%22&filter=0).